# Using a datepicker with Phalcon Volt template engine

Tags: php, date, phalcon, volt

I am pretty new to the Phalcon PHP framework and the Volt template engine.
So far I really like it though.

One thing that I can't figure out however, is how to implement a date picker to a date field.
I have a date field defined as below, but rather than having to manually input a date I would like the user to select a date from a date picker.

```
<?php echo Tag::dateField(array("finishdate", "size" => 8, "maxlength" => 8, "type" => "date")) ?>
```

I thought that maybe it would automatically get a date picker if it was defined as a date field, or maybe there was an option somewhere, but I have looked all over internet and I can't find anything.

I would be very grateful if someone knew how to solve this?

I am also trying to figure out the Volt textArea and I have problems finding any information regarding this as well. I can't seem to get the text area to show as a text box. There just seems to be very little information from users regarding Phalcon Volt. Is no one using this?

Answer (score 1):

I did it! I used datepicker (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). I share with you the code.

Form:

```
$fecha = new Text('fecha_final');
    $fecha->setLabel('Fecha Final');
    $fecha->addValidators(array(
        new PresenceOf(array(
            'message' => 'Por favor pon una fecha límite'
            ))
        ));
    $this->add($fecha);
```

Controller:

```
public function nuevakeywordAction(){
    $auth = $this->session->get('auth');
    $permiso = $auth['active'];
    if($permiso!='A'){return $this->forward('servicios/index');}

    $form = new NuevakeywordForm;

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {

        $trackeable = $this->request->getPost('trackeable', array('string', 'striptags'));
        $idcliente = $this->request->getPost('idcliente');
        $fecha = $this->request->getPost('fecha');

        $keyword = new Keyword();
        $keyword->trackeable = $trackeable;
        $keyword->cliente_idcliente = $idcliente;
        $keyword->fecha_inicial = new Phalcon\Db\RawValue('now()');
        $keyword->fecha_final = $fecha;
        if ($keyword->save() == false) {
            foreach ($keyword->getMessages() as $message) {
                $this->flash->error((string) $message);
            }
        } else {
            $this->tag->setDefault('trackeable', '');
            $this->tag->setDefault('idcliente', '');
            $this->tag->setDefault('fecha', '');
            $this->flash->success('Keyword agregada correctamente');
            return $this->forward('admin/verkeywords');
        }
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

View:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<section class="container animated fadeInUp">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div id="login-wrapper">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">     
                    Registrar Nueva Keyword
                </h3>  
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ form('admin/nuevakeyword/', 'id': 'nuevakeywordForm', 'onbeforesubmit': 'return false') }}

                <fieldset>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        {{ form.label('trackeable', ['class': 'control-label']) }}
                        <div class="controls">
                            {{ form.render('trackeable', ['class': 'form-control']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        {{ form.label('idcliente', ['class': 'control-label']) }}
                        <div class="controls">
                            {{ form.render('idcliente', ['class': 'form-control']) }}                           
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        {{ form.label('fecha_final', ['class': 'control-label']) }}
                        <div id="datepicker" class="controls">
                            {{ form.render('fecha_final', ['class': 'form-control']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions">
                        {{ submit_button('Insertar', 'class': 'btn btn-primary', 'onclick': 'return SignUp.validate();') }}
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $("#fecha_final").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The date field merely uses HTML5's date field. If you want a date picker, you must use a Javascript date picker library.

As for text areas and text fields, you should use the function `text_field()` to create a text field, and `text_area()` to create a text area. The list of functions you can use are in the [Volt – Using tag helpers](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#using-tag-helpers) documentation page.

Comment: Yes, if I am using it in the template, but that generates the same code as above. I have understood I will need to use a client script for date picker, but I am just not sure how to implement it with the Volt syntax. At this point it looks like I might have to abandon the Volt template engine. I just can't find any examples, so it appears to be very few that uses it. All the samples are on Phalcons own pages.

Comment: I actually just tried it in Chrome and it works as I expected it to. A date picker is automatically created when you use a dateField. It does not seem to work in IE 11 though, unless there is a setting? I tried Compatibility mode, but no joy.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the first part of your comment. The same code as above? You mean `text_field()` and `text_area()` generate the same tag? Also, what you need to do to implement date pickers is usually to use `text_field()` to create a text field, and set its `class` to something, then call the appropriate function in Javascript. In other words, creating a date picker in Phalcon is just like creating it with normal HTML. Have you done it before? If not, you can ask a separate, Javascript-related question.

Comment: IE 11 doesn't support the `date` HTML5 tag. Using a Javascript library instead is usually safer and more cross-browser.